# "Send" keyboard keys to a control

Tags: .net, winforms, keyboard, tabcontrol

In a `WinForm` I have a `TabControl`.

The TabControl, normally, responds to several key events, like `Ctrl+Tab`, `Ctrl+Shift+Tab`, `Home`, `End` etc...

But in my case I have in form an other control that inhibits these keys, so I need to "send" the keys "manually"(by code) to my TabControl.

Is there something like `MyTabControl.SendKeys(myKeysEventArg.Keys)`?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution: you can verified if TabControl is focused before use ProcessCmdKey to inhibits some keys.

```
Select Case keyData

    Case Keys.Home And Not Me.TabControl1.Focused
        MsgBox("disabled!")
        Return True

    Case Else
        Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)

End Select
```